# Unable to Retreive Blend's Data in Looker Studio when One of Table is empty

Tags: python, database, django-models, looker-studio

This Dashboard/Report on Looker Studio is used to retrieve data from the database to provide a easy view for the team. The join between the tables are as follows :[image: JOIN]

The data is Filtered out on 2 basis, Brand_ID and date range. Like this: [image: like this]

This Dashboard is working for every other Brand_ID but this particular Brand_ID (26) for which there's no data in the social_media_adset:[image: social_media_adset Table] for the date range 1 aug - 20 aug.

Social_media_adset model in django:

```
lass Adset(models.Model):
    brandId                         = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    adset_name                      = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    adset_id                        = models.BigIntegerField()
    campaign_id                     = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True)
    campaign_name                   = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    impressions                     = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status                          = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    spend                           = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    clicks                          = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_currency                = models.CharField(max_length=159, blank=True)
    unique_clicks                   = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cpm                             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    cpc                             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    reach                           = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    type                            = models.CharField(max_length=99 ,blank=True)
    date_start                      = models.DateField(blank=True)
    date_stop                       = models.DateField(blank=True)
    ctr                             = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    purchase_roas                   = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    purchases                       = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('adset_id', 'campaign_id', 'date_start', 'date_stop')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.adset_name
```

But the data in Website_order Table [image: website_order Table] is present for the following range.

website_order model in django:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id              = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    brand_id        = models.IntegerField()
    order_id        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_list   = models.CharField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    date            = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    time            = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    total           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6,null=True, blank=True)
    product_name    = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True, blank=True)
    quantity        = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    currency        = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    customer        = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='website_customer', null=True, blank=True)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='processing')
    city            = models.CharField(max_length=199, null=True, blank=True)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=199,null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code        = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('brand_id', 'product_name', 'order_id', 'date', 'time')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.order_id)
```

Verified through Django Admin panel that the data is present:[image: Django Admin Panel]

I've manually checked the database and ran the join query between 2 tables Website_order and social_media_adset, the data was present.

The Dashboard was working for every other brand_id and data ranges.

Tried to plot the table of website_orders without creating any blend/join in looker studio, The data plotted out as it should be i.e brand_id 26 had data for date range 1 aug - 20 aug.

Please help me debug this problem out. if you need any other resource to look at, please let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, The Problem was how we were joining the tables. Every table was joined with the `website_order` table, except for the `Brand` table, It was joined with the `facebook_adset` table. And when i joined the `Brand` table with the `website_order` table. The output was as we were expecting. What I think happened is, The drop-down list had elements from `Brand` from which the whole dashboard is to be filtered, and then it was joined with `facebook_adset` table which had no elements for that specific date. So the join between `facebook_adset` and `website_order` had nothing to be joined upon. if anyone have any other explainations to this, please enlighten us. Thank-You.

Comment: Note that this would be classified as a case of the issue being "**Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo**" as it was not joined to the same table as the other data sources (Typo being about the join)